# How do I add content of number of files in a directory into same number of lists

Tags: python

I have lot of .txt files with list of names (each line - one name) and I want to append each file content into a single list. These lists I want to have as sublists in one big list. I need to have content of each file as separated sublist in the final_product list.

Content of 1.txt could be:
NAME1
NAME2
NAME3 ...
Content of 2.txt could be:
NAME4
NAME5
NAME6 ...
.
.
.
Content of N.txt could be:
NAMEn
NAMEo
NAMEp

The output should be [[NAME1,NAME2,NAME3],[NAME4,NAME5,NAME6],...[NAMEn,NAMEo,NAMEp]]

I am able to write a code, where is for each file written command what to do, but I need to write a loop for all the files.

```
 name1 = []
 name2 = []
 .
 .
 .
 nameN = []

 a = open(r'U:/1.txt','r')
 for line in a:
     name1.append(line.strip())

 b = open(r'U:/2.txt','r')
 for line in b:
     name2.append(line.strip())
 .
 .
 .
 N = open(r'U:/N.txt','r')
 for line in N:
     nameN.append(line.strip())

 final_product = [name1,name2,...,nameN]
```

EDIT:

I tried to solve the problem with this new code:

```
import os
list_of_files = []
product = []
final_product = []

working_dir = r"U:/Work/"
os.chdir(working_dir)

def create_sublists(fname):
    with open(fname, 'r', encoding = 'ansi') as f:
        for line in f:
            product.append(line.strip()) #append each line from file to product
    final_product.append(product) #append the product list to final_product
    product.clear() #clear the product list
    f.close()

#create list of all files in the working directory
for file in os.listdir(working_dir):
    if file.endswith('.txt'):
        list_of_files.append(file)

for file in list_of_files:
    create_sublists(file)

print(final_product)
```

I thought that it will work in this way: first file will write its content into list product, this list will be appended into list final_product, the list product will be cleared, then will be appended second file ....
But the reality is that the function creates as many empty sublists in the final product as many files I have in the folder, e.g. for 6 files in the folder:
[ [], [], [], [], [], [] ]
Can you please try to help me?

Comment: Please give a minimal example of input and ouput expected. Do you want the file names in the list? or The content of the file in list?

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly

```
import os

loc = r'path/to/your/directory/'   # if you are on windows use the r
files = os.listdir(path)  # list of all files in the directory

final_product = []
for file in files:   #Loop over the files and add the lines
     a = open(loc+file,'r')
     for line in a:
         final_product.append([line.strip()])
     a.close()
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need to have content of each file as separated sublist in the final_product list. This works very well as append all the content into one list (not separated as sublists).

Comment: FIle closing? I highly recommend to use `with` to avoid forgetting it.

Comment: @hejmatt check the edit. I have added closing the file as well. But as the comment points out using `with` would be a better way to go.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```
import os
path = "path/to/txt-files-directory"
all_txt_files = os.listdir(path)
txt_list = []
for txt in all_txt_files:
    f = open(path + "/" + txt)
    data = f.read().splitlines()# will return all data as a list
    txt_list.append(data)
    f.close()
```

Comment: I would highly recommend to use `with`.

Comment: @Adirio I've already added f.close() to properly close the file. No need to use `with` here

Comment: It was a recommendation. `with` does not only prevent you forgetting to add `f.close()`, it has additional advantages in case something between the `open` and `close` functions breaks.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply list all the text files first

```
import os
final_product = []
for file in os.listdir("U:/"):
    with open("U:/{}".format(file), "r") as file_object:
        content = file_object.readline().strip()
        final_product.append(content)
```

Now every index of `final_product` represents a text file's content.

Comment: Try `os.chmod('U:/', 0)` before `os.listdir` after the declaration of `final_product`

Comment: No error now, great. But I got in the final_product list only names from first lines of each file and they are not separated as sublists.

Comment: try `file_object.readlines()` instead of `file_object.readline()`. Would be awsome if you can provide 1 text file.

Comment: I tried to write the code in different way. It is all written in my original question.

Comment: So if you have a text file with content like `hello my name is ibtihaj`, the function `readline()` will return a string object like `'hello my name is ibtihaj\n'` where as the function `readlines()` will return a list object like `['hello my name is ibtihaj\n']`. Now given you have 2 name in a single text file on every new line i.e `A`, `B`, the function `readlines()` will return a list object like `['A\n', 'B\n']`. So every file's content will be in a list and every index of the `final_product` will be a sub-list with the content of every text file.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this

```
import os

final_product = [name1,name2,......]
counter = 0
for filename in os.listdir(directory): 
        a = open(filename,'r')
        for line in a:
            arrayOFnames[counter].append(line.strip())
        counter = counter + 1
```

Comment: This is not valid python, even without the `...`, append will fail as name1 is not a list. Additionally python variables must be named `like_this` not `likeTHIS`.